# REST call using PKCS12 certificate - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring-boot, keystore, pkcs#12, jks

I am trying to make a REST GET call using [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) and also trying to configure the PKCS12 digital certificate.

I have imported the certificate in Chrome as well as in Postman and I am able to make the call successfully, however when I am trying to do the same in Java code, it's throwing an error possibly because of wrong config/code.

Here is my RestTemplate code -

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    KeyStore clientStore = null;
    try {
        clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("/tmp/cert_SHA2.p12"), "password".toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 
    SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    sslContextBuilder.useProtocol("TLS");
    try {
        sslContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(clientStore, "password".toCharArray());
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(clientStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = null;
    try {
        sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContextBuilder.build());
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Code to call the REST API

```
String uri = "someuri";
RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
 
System.out.println(result);
```

Error Message:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:113) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder$TrustManagerDelegate.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextBuilder.java:190) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1099) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:290) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:259) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller.EmployeeController.process(EmployeeController.java:267) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1** -
I have commented out the RestTemplate code and converted the p12 cert to jks and added this bit

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cert_SHA2.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Now when I run the project, I am getting the error below:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:783) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:315) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:59) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getTrustManagers(SSLContextImpl.java:882) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:854) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1027) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:332) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:99) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:991) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.openConnection(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:180) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:615) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller.EmployeeController.process(EmployeeController.java:270) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

I have already verified the password is correct. I have also verified the jks file is not corrupted by using the following command in terminal.

```
keytool -v -list -keystore cert_SHA2.jks
```

It shows me all the details about the certificate.

Please help.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work that can be avoided. Can't your just import your certificate to a jks file and then simply provide the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path and -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=  params to the JVM then you can reduce your restTemplate() method to just return new RestTemplate();

Comment: Hi @RobScully, I have tried the suggestion and now it is throwing a different error. I have updated the question, please see "Edit 1". Thanks

Comment: PKCS#12 is a keystore format, not a certificate or certificate format. Your *truststore* doesn't trust the peer certificate. You don't need to supply the truststore password, but if you do you need to get it right, and you didn't.

Comment: @user2798227 Is the password you used for creating the pkcs12 file the same as the password you used for creating the JKS file? If not you’ll have to recreate the JKS file with the same password. See the answer on this page:

https://community.apigee.com/questions/48988/getting-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was.html

Comment: @RobScully, yes it's the same password for both p12 and jks file.